# i tried opening a python file and got this, please can anyone help out

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\justiceme1212\Downloads\Archive-10db\zombiev13\v13.py", line 63, in <module>
    tool = raw_input(g + "["+r+"*"+g+"] Choose tool : ")
NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined
```

Comment: By the tag, it seems like you're using Python 3. You should be using `input` instead of `raw_input`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. In the future, you need to make your question titles actually describe the problem you're having. Please read [ask].

Comment: please how to use input instead of raw_input to open the python file

Comment: Where did you get this file? Did you write it yourself? How are you running it?

Comment: thank you i was able to edit my python scripts with works  fine but another options from my last showing same error and when i checked throuth the my scripts the module not have any raw_input or input to edit...the error message--
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\justiceme1212\Downloads\Archive-10db\zombiev13\Tools\Tool2\priv8.py", line 78, in <module>
    dorklist = raw_input("{}\n[{}*{}] Dorklist : ".format(settings.green,settings.red,settings.green))
NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined

Comment: any help please

Comment: i downloaded it online to run as python v13.py

Comment: i don`t know how to write script yet..i`ll be glad if you got any aticle you can recommended to help please

Answer (score 0):

Below are some easy suggested steps to help you:

- Open "v13.py" in Notepad
- Change " tool = raw_input(g + "["+r+"*"+g+"] Choose tool : ") " to " tool = input(g + "["+r+"*"+g+"] Choose tool : ") "
- Attempt to run program again

- If you are interested please check [this link](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3111/).

Comment: i edited the python file with IDLE already and the program now run fine..but some of the tool options shows this error again..something like this...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\justiceme1212\Downloads\Archive-10db\zombiev13\Tools\Tool2\priv8.py", line 78, in <module>
    dorklist = raw_input("{}\n[{}*{}] Dorklist : ".format(settings.green,settings.red,settings.green))
NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined..

Comment: i opened the python file again look for those specific tools but no raw_input was included on the script..this one of them......elif tool == "2":
 os.chdir("Tools/Tool2")
 os.system("python priv8.py"

Comment: the newly defined error of "raw_input" is from another referenced script called "priv8.py". I also think one of the easy fixes for you is to download and install python2 and run the program with it.

py2 and py3 can run together on the same machine just pay attention how you call them. Below are two examples from CMD:

[python2] C:\Users\justiceme1212\path\to\file> python script.py
[python3] C:\Users\justiceme1212\path\to\file> python3 script.py

Comment: oh okay.. thank you so much, i`ll probably download and install the python2 ,sorry for the late reply,,have been up to a lot lately...my pleasure